# Generating sequence of ID's using Recursion in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, common-table-expression, recursive-query

We have a table defined `transactions` as;

```
id
-----
 0
 1
 2
 5
 6
 8
 9
 10
 15
```

As seen, the id's are not consecutive. The goal is to identify missing id's. I am trying to first generate all id's using recursion. And then use left join to identify missing id's.
Here the expected output should be `3,4,7,11,12,13,14.`

Here is my approach;

```
    WITH RECURSIVE CTE (id) AS(
    
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM transactions
    UNION ALL
     SELECT id+1
     FROM CTE
     WHERE id<=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM transactions)
    
    
)

 SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

The number goes only unto 15 in `transactions` table. But I am getting following error;

`ERROR 3636 (HY000) at line 289: Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.` Please note that MySQL version is 8.0.22. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What if zero was missing?

Answer (score 3):

Your code should not be raising that error, as shown in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05d719137d57aa21d5b9fcf9ac67716b).

You could, however, optimize the query a little by avoiding the subquery in the recursive member. That would be:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select min(id) as id, max(id) as max_id from transactions 
    union all
    select id + 1, max_id from cte where id < max_id
)
select c.id
from cte c
where not exists (select 1 from transactions t where t.id = c.id)
```

However that's still pretty much a brute force approach. If you have a lot of rows and a few missing numbers, we can make the query more efficient by generating only the ranges of missing numbers:

```
with recursive 
    data as (
        select id, lead(id) over(order by id) lead_id from transactions
    ),
    cte as (
        select id + 1 as id, lead_id - 1 as  max_id from data where lead_id > id + 1  
        union all
        select id + 1, max_id from cte where id < max_id
    )
select id from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a849b2dc1da63d7b63ede6b83ea074fe)**

Comment: @ GMB Your opinion make sense. it seems there is some hidden case in the platform where the recursive  depth is getting exceeded.I was wondering,  are you aware of how to increase cte_max_recursion_depth? thanks

Comment: @jay as you would change  any other setting in mysql: via config file or through the set statement.

Comment: @ GMB Appreciate your help. There is an edge case, I am wondering about. If the `id` begins from a nonzero value, say 3. In this case, 0,1,2 are missing values, which should be in the output.Is it possible to modify the above logic to include these edge cases? thanks